# Flutter local notification is not working as expected on IOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-local-notification

My codes are below. It is working very well on Android devices but when I click the notification, it doesn't open specific screen on IOS. It just opens the app. I want it open the spesific screen.

```
    Future<void>  initSettings() async {
    
    
    var initAndorid = AndroidInitializationSettings('my_logo');
    var initIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestAlertPermission: false,
    );
    var initSetting =InitializationSettings(android: initAndorid, iOS: initIOS);
     notificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetting,
        onSelectNotification: notificationSelected);
  }

  Future notificationSelected(String? payload) async {
     
     await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SpesificScreen())
    ); 
  }
```

It's working on Android devices. What should I do? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you found any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code on your app startup to give notification's payload or details that cause to open app and do navigate or every other work we want to do :

```
var details = await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
if (details.didNotificationLaunchApp) {
 await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SpesificScreen())
 ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried this code but nothing change unfortunately. I don't know why but notificationSelected is not working when I click the notification. So I think this is the problem.

Comment: Same code is working on Android devices btw

Comment: Do you follow the iOS setup for flutter local notification? you should add some code to your AppDelegate.m/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Yes I did it. My problem is just about what happens when I click the notification. I do not have any problems receiving notifications.

Comment: I added these codes in my AppDelegate.swift                                         if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}

Comment: where did you put my answer's code? it should be working.

Comment: I put in notificationSelected. It's working on Android.

Comment: In notificationSelected method? no, you should add this to your app startup like the first-page initState method.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll try. Thanks again.

Comment: I added the code in main.dart file but it didn't work. What is my fault?

Comment: Any update on this ? Have you fixed it.
I am also facing same issue while clicking notification its moving to main page but payload is not working.